# Enabling the Wordpress Divi theme top header menu

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way to activate the Divi top header menu (that which is given by default everytime a new Divi project is started, with the default encircled "D" logo)
For some reason I did never get that option when I started a Divi project, and now I have some main menu problems that I don't want to have.
I have tried to activate things in the Theme Customizer, but it has no effect.
I suspect the reason I never got that Divi top header menu was that I created a child project on the Divi theme (?)
Any help would be appreciated greatly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out: In Page attributes there is a setting where one can select "Standard template", or "Blank page". The latter excludes the top header menu bar.